# How to use onSnapshot to update props through Redux

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, redux, google-cloud-firestore

I'm learning how to code and I'm really struggling with the following issue:

I'm building a chat app and I need to display new messages as soon as they are submitted. As a result, I thought about using onSnapshot(). Every time I used onSnapshot() in basic one-page exercises, it worked. Now, however, I have a project with 3 folders (src; public; functions). For all my functionality, I got/sent data using this.props.functionName() and manage state with Redux and then, the backend would return a promise.

My question is, how do I use onSnapshot to update my props given that I cannot call the function nor use return.

I tried using the admin sdk directly in the components, but firebase issued a warning in the console saying I should only use it in the backend.

Basically, how do I send the following array to the component I need it to be sent to without invoking the function?

```
exports.messages = (req, res) => {
    db.collection('messages').onSnapshot(snapshot => {
        let messages = [];
        snapshot.forEach(doc => {
          messages.push(doc.data())
        });
      })
}
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

You can find in [this tutorial](https://medium.com/javascript-in-plain-english/firebase-firestore-database-realtime-updates-with-react-hooks-useeffect-346c1e154219) a way to update firebase props that might work for you. The sample code they use is:

```
useEffect(() => {
  const unsubscribe = props.firebase
    .db.collection('myCollectionName')
    .onSnapshot(snapshot => {
      if (snapshot.size) {
        // we have something
        ** Handle returned data **
      } else {
        // it's empty
      }
    })
return () => {
    unsubscribe()
  }
}, [props.firebase])
```

And this other one for handling returned data:

```
let myDataArray = []
snapshot.forEach(doc =>
  myDataArray.push({ ...doc.data() })
)
setData(myDataArray)
```